# Data not properly being scraped from a given website using python

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup, scrape

I am trying to extract golf course information from the "thegolfcourse.net" website. I aim to gather the name,address,and phone number of 18000+ golf courses in the United States from the website. I ran the my script but it does not produce all the data from the website. There are 18000+ golf courses but I only get about 200+ sites downloaded from the website. I dont know if my loop is wrong or I am not accessing all the data based on my code and further I get spaces in my data and I am wondering how I will extract the data properly.

Here is my script:

```
import csv
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

courses_list = []

for i in range(56):
 url="http://www.thegolfcourses.net/page/{}?ls&location&orderby=title".format(i)
 r = requests.get(url)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)


g_data2=soup.find_all("article")


for item in g_data2:
  try:
    name = item.contents[5].find_all("a")[0].text
    print name
  except:
        name=''      
  try:
    phone= item.contents[13].find_all("p",{"class":"listing-phone"})[0].text
  except:
      phone=''
  try:
    address= item.contents[13].find_all("p",{"class":"listing-address"})[0].text
  except:
      address=''

  course=[name,phone,address]
  courses_list.append(course)


with open ('PGN.csv','a') as file:
  writer=csv.writer(file)
  for row in courses_list:
          writer.writerow([s.encode("utf-8") for s in row])
```

Comment: What would your desired output look like? Edit your question with an example of what you want it to look like.

Comment: At first glance, you seem to be scraping the first 56 pages, but I see 1,907 pages on the website. In terms of extra spaces, you're probably getting leading and trailing whitespace. Use `.strip()` on the strings to clean it up.

Comment: How do I go about getting all 1907 pages?

Comment: @Gonzalo68 check out the answer I provided on how to grab what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your code didn't grab everything because you set the range to 56. Which is fine for testing but if you want to grab everything you need to set

```
for i in range(1907):
```

This goes to 1907 because it will stop at 1907 due to adding the `.format(i+1)` to the URL portion.

Also, you had several errors in your `for` loops. These may have been issues when you posted to StackOverflow but I cleaned them up anyway.

When I ran your code the first time I saw what the 'spacing' was. When you parsed the HTML, you parsed it looking for the `article` tag but that tag is also taking care of the first search result which displays the `"Listings found for "" near ""` in your example link. You can narrow down your scope when web scraping by using something like I did here:

```
g_data2 = soup.find_all("article",{"itemtype":"http://schema.org/Organization"})
```

This will make the scraping easier on you by only grabbing data that is found within the tag containing `article` and `itemtype = http://schema.org/Organization"`. That is unique enough and luckily all the entries match that format.

I also changed your `csvwriter` from `a` to `wb` which starts a new CSV every time the script is run and does not append to it.

**Here's the final script:**

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

courses_list = []

for i in range(1907):
    url="http://www.thegolfcourses.net/page/{}?ls&location&orderby=title".format(i+1)
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    #print soup
    g_data2 = soup.find_all("article",{"itemtype":"http://schema.org/Organization"})

    for item in g_data2:
        try:
            name = item.find_all("h2",{'class':'entry-title'})[0].text
            print name
        except:
            name=''
            print "No Name found!"
        try:
            phone= item.find_all("p",{"class":"listing-phone"})[0].text
        except:
            phone=''
            print "No Phone found!"
        try:
            address= item.find_all("p",{"class":"listing-address"})[0].text
        except:
            address=''
            print "No Address found!"
        course=[name,phone,address]
        courses_list.append(course)

with open ('PGN.csv','wb') as file:
    writer=csv.writer(file)
    for row in courses_list:
        writer.writerow([s.encode("utf-8") for s in row])
```